# Writing Cookies In Asp.net WebApi

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I'm integrating with an sso system that requires setting a cookie during a POST operation. I don't see any way to do this using an HttpResponseMessage. I could take a dependency on HttpResponseBase in my controller, but that seems very ghetto. Any other way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [this discussion](http://forums.asp.net/t/1790339.aspx/1), this is now a bit easier:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(int id, [FromBody]string value) {
 var result = this.Request.CreateResponse();
 result.Headers.AddCookies(new[] { new CookieHeaderValue("name", "value") });
 return result;
}
```

They [keep changing this type of stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10357526/cant-get-asp-net-4-web-api-to-return-status-code-201-created-for-successful) though... ([further reading](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/discussions/350492))

Answer (score 1):

You could return a `Set-Cookie-Header` using the Headers-Collection of the `HttpResponseMessage`.

Comment: can't we use `HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add()`. Any problem other than accessing static property?

Comment: HttpContext.Current should not be used from within Web API Controllers.

Comment: Any specific reasons you would like to share?

Comment: It's because it is not available when self-hosting APIs instead of using IIS

Comment: Thanx Alex. It means if we are using IIS to host api then there would be no poblem?

Comment: It is easier method. You can use this when u know, u will never need `selfhosting`