# Can't get ASP.NET 4 Web API to return Status Code "201 - Created" for successful POST

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to return an HTTP Status Code of `201 Created` for a RESTful POST operation using ASP.NET 4 Web API, but I always get a `200 OK`.

I'm currently debugging on IIS 7.5.7600.16385, VS 2010 Professional, Windows 7 64-bit Professional.

```
public MyResource Post(MyResource myResource)
{
    MyResource createdResource;
    ...
    HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
    response.ClearHeaders(); // added this later, no luck
    response.ClearContent(); // added this later, no luck
    response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Created;
    SetCrossOriginHeaders(response);
    return createdResource;
}
```

I have seen other examples where `HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode` is set before returning data, so I didn't think this would be a problem.  I haven't tracked it down in the MVC 4 source yet.

*(This is related to my investigations with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10336733/different-return-types-for-asp-net-mvc-4-web-api) but different enough topic to warrant its own question)*

I am not sure whether the problem is IIS or the Web API.  I will do further tests to narrow it down.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`HttpContext.Current` is a hangover from the past.

You need to define response as `HttpResponseMessage<T>`:

```
public HttpResponseMessage<MyResource> Post(MyResource myResource)
{
    .... // set the myResource
    return new HttpResponseMessage<MyResource>(myResource)
            {
                StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Created
            };
}
```

---

## UPDATE

As you might notice from the comments, this approach works with **beta** release. **Not** the RC.

Comment: Thanks!  That did it.   I'm actually just returning HttpResponseMessage so that I can return different content type if necessary, but instantiating HttpResponseMessage<T> as needed, which also takes care of my related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10336733/different-return-types-for-asp-net-mvc-4-web-api.

Comment: @MikeJansen Don't get too used to HttpResponseMessage<T> of T as it is going away in future builds. See http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/discussions/350492

Comment: @DarrelMiller - thanks, I have converted to HttpRequestMessage.CreateResponse<T>() !

Comment: `HttpResponseMessage` cannot be used with type arguments.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
return Request.CreateResponse<MyResource>(HttpStatusCode.Created, createdResource);
```